# List error after second click

Tags: javascript

in my app I have a views that retrieve a list of a certain content type which links to the specific node.
When I click for the first time it's ok, app brings me to the page that shows the content but when I go back and I click on another item in the list, the page that shoud shows content goes blank.

Any idea?

Thank you,
Cris.

> UPDATED ON 2017-08-18

***Page that shows the list:***

```
function list_articles_list_row(view, row, variables) {
  try {

      var title_html = "<div class='desc'><span class='nome'>" + row.nome+" "+row.cognome.charAt(0)+".</span> -  "+" "+row.title+"</div>";
       var image_html = "<div class='thumb'>"+theme('image', { path: row.img.src })+"</div>";

      var link = l('' + image_html + title_html, 'singlegiftapp/' + row.nid);
      return link;




   }
  catch (error) { console.log('list_articles_list_row - ' + error); }
}
```

***Single page item:***

```
    function single_page(nid) {
     var content = {};
      content['ite'] = {
        theme: 'jqm_item_list',
        title: '',
        items: [],
        attributes: { id: 'ite' + nid }
      };
      return content;
     }



function single_pageshow(nid) {
  var path_to_view = 'singlegiftapp/'+nid;
  views_datasource_get_view_result(path_to_view, {
    'success':function(data){

    if (data.nodes.length > 0) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data.nodes, function(index, object){
              var row = object.node;


             var image_html = theme('image', { path: row.img.src });

               var description =
                '<h1>' + row.title + '</h1>' +
                '<p>Price suggested:  ' + row.Prezzo + '</p>' ;
               var dato = t(description+image_html);
              items.push(dato);

        });
         drupalgap_item_list_populate("#ite" + nid, items);
      }
    }




  });

}
```

***Thank you so much Tyler for your help!***

Comment: Please share your code that you are using to build the page/view/etc. Most likely you need to append a unique id to the end of your View since DrupalGap 7 is a multi-page app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in your `page_callback` implementation, but I am guessing you just need to make your id for your item list be dynamic:

```
var itemListId = 'ite' + nid;
```

Then in your `pageshow`, do something like this:

```
drupalgap_item_list_populate("#ite" + nid, items);
```

DrupalGap 7 is a multi-page application, so as you navigate around previously visited pages remain in the DOM, so any `id` that you add to elements should be unique for that page. Which means typically you just need to append an entity `type/id` to the element's id, and you should be good to go.